# How to hide columns based on condition in yii2 gridview?

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have placed a conditional statement in my index page.

**Controller**

```
$type ="402"; // type can me 401 and 403
 $searchModel = new MdcmetersdataSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'type'  => $type
        ]);
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php
if($type == '401')
{
    $columns = [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'device_id',
        'cust_id',
        'msn',
        'current_p1',
        'current_p2',
        'current_p3',        
        'data_date_time',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ];



}else if($type == '402')
{
    $columns = [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'device_id',
        'cust_id',
        'msn',
        'voltage_p1',
        'voltage_p2',
        'voltage_p3',      
        'data_date_time',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ];
}
else if($type == "403")
{
    $columns = [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'device_id',
        'cust_id',
        'msn',
        'kwh',
        'data_date_time',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ];

}
else
{
    $columns = [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'device_id',
        'cust_id',
        'msn',
        'voltage_p1',
        'voltage_p2',
        'voltage_p3',
        'current_p1',
        'current_p2',
        'current_p3',
        'device_id',
        'kwh',


        'data_date_time',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ];

}
?>
<?=
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => $columns
]);
?>
```

As mentioned above that the value of `$type` can be `401, 402 and 403`. So I am trying to check whether my condition is working or not. So I pass `402` which means only the columns with `voltages` value should be shown, but I got the following result

[image]

I want to hide the red circled columns, i.e. I just want to show the data of that particular `$type` value.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: your question si not clear  to me.. In your sample seems you want show only the rows  with volt values and hide the rows  without value??

Comment: Yes that exactly what I want

Comment: I have already posted  an answer   .. hope is useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want hide/don't show the rows without volt value for 402 the simples way is aavoid selection in search query .
For this you could add  a proper 402 search funtion in the search model

```
/**
 * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
 *
 * @param array $params
 *
 * @return ActiveDataProvider
 */
public function search($params)
{
   ........

    return $dataProvider;
}


public function search402($params)
{
    $query = YourModel::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andWhere(['not', ['volt1' => null]]);

    ;
    return $dataProvider;
}
```

and in controller  manage the search function you really need

```
$searchModel = new MdcmetersdataSearch();
switch($type){
    case '402':
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search402(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    break;
    ....
}
```

Comment: I have tried another method. But I am sure this method will also work.